# How to assess what apps or settings are causing high CPU usage from system_server process on Android Nougat?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, command-line

I am running root Android Nougat on a Nexus 6P. My battery is draining in <3hrs. When I run `su -c htop` it shows system_server is using >400% CPU. I have now factory reset 3 times and each time this behavior surfaces after 1-2 days of normal usage.

system_server seems to be a generic process not tied to any particular app or setting.

What Linux diagnostic commands can I use to systematically trace which apps or settings are related to this issue. I have tried things like wakelock tracking apps with no luck. I have also tried looking at `adb logcat` but I am not really sure what to look for.